# Auto add shipping line item

Tags: commerce, rules

I want to auto add flat rate shipping cost to any order and display it in the shopping cart summary.

I am using Commerce Shipping and [Commerce Flat Rate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) modules. I can't know how to implement it using rules.

I found [this post](https://drupal.org/node/1452322) but it didn't help me.

what I need is to automatically add $10 on every order for shipping, I will disable the Shipping Service Panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Rules. Here is an example:

```
{
    "rules_auto_add_shipping_service" : {
      "LABEL" : "Auto-add shipping service",
      "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
      "OWNER" : "rules",
      "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_order", "commerce_shipping", "entity" ],
      "ON" : { "commerce_order_update" : [] },
      "IF" : [
        { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-order:type" ], "value" : "commerce_order" } },
        { "commerce_order_contains_product" : {
            "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
            "product_id" : "YOUR-SKU-HERE",
            "operator" : "\u003E=",
            "value" : "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "DO" : [
        { "commerce_shipping_delete_shipping_line_items" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ] } },
        { "commerce_shipping_method_collect_rates" : {
            "shipping_method_name" : "flat_rate",
            "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ]
          }
        },
        { "commerce_shipping_rate_apply" : {
            "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ],
            "shipping_service_name" : [ "" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Just change the SKU or the other conditions to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this out of the box with FLAT RATE.

Just add your new FLAT RATE for $10 (yoursite.com/admin/commerce/config/shipping then click ADD NEW FLAT RATE) and it will show up in the shipping pane already selected when checking out.
It will also create a new line item on the cart summary for SHIPPING.

This will add a $10 flat rate shipping method to every order
 - if this is not what you are looking for please clarify, hope this helps.